# How should I install windows with a 2 drive setup?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, installation, ssd

My PC has 2 drives: a small solid state, and a large hard drive. Obviously I want to install Windows on the solid state, but how can I configure it such that all other installations are defaulted to the hard drive? I previously had a similar setup but ran into issues with my solid state filling up due to random things being installed there

Comment: It is as simply as selecting the partition and disk of your SSD during the installation process.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I know how to install windows on my solid-state, the question is how do I install it such that everything else defaults to the hard drive, not the solid state.

Comment: You don't.  You install it on the SSD then change the configuration so those things that can be moved, point to the HDD.

Comment: How small is small?

Comment: The alternative is you install Windows normally, configure it so everything else is on another disk or partition, then create a new .wim file.  You then apply that .WIM file to the SSD.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

1. Enter into Start>Run: %systemroot%\syswow64\regedit
2. Go to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ SOFTWARE \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion
3. Change the Path in DWORDs ProgramFilesDir, ProgramFilesDir (x86) to the new path, probably just changing the drive letter.

See hazard in comments. :P

Enjoy.

Comment: No side effects at all?

Comment: Ha. The Microsoft article outlines the issues. I wouldn't do it myself, but when you're desperate... https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/933700?wa=wsignin1.0 Personally I'd just spend the $85 on a 256GB SSD and forget about it.

Comment: Does this not answer a different question though?  This explains how to change it, not how to install it, with it already changed.

Comment: @Ramhound Im fine with changing it after installation. The important part is that once Im done with all my setup (including windows installation and anything after) I have the system the way I want.

Comment: So what is your question exactly?  I thought you already knew how to move the user profile to another partition besides the system partition.